# Access hash by primary key - ruby rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I thought this could be done trivially but I am unable to do so.

My current code is:

```
@player_types = squad.player_types
```

Now I loop and lookup for the id,

```
params[:player_types].each do |p_type|
  @player_types.find(p_type[:id])
end
```

Why does `@player_types.find(p_type[:id])` have to execute the the `select` query when I look up the server logs, havent I loaded this. Is it because of the lazy evaluation and is there a way to load everything at the start and access it as an index in the hash?

Comment: what do you meant load everithing at start? what is that **eveything**?

Comment: I think your code needs more context. You should describe the result set that you want, the controller action that this code relates to, and the data type of params[:player_types].

Comment: Why wouldn't you just look up the `@player_types` directly? Is `player_types` a table with a PlayerType` model? Is `params[:player_types]` an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better way to use [`arel` gem](https://github.com/rails/arel), and to select all record with specific *ids* is this:

```
ids = params[:player_types].map {|v| v[:id] }
@player_types.where(@player_types.class.arel_table[:id].in(ids))
```

Answer (score 0):

If `player_types` is a table, you can directly select all of the player_types in the `params[:player_types]` array by passing the array to a `where` condition.

```
@player_types = PlayerType.where(id: params[:player_types])
```

Comment: What do you mean by "edit your question with the description"? You want me to edit the OP's question?

Comment: No, I meant *why* does your answer answer OP's question. I think it's ok now.